# One p:poll pausing the other?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a JSF2 page with two PrimeFaces p:poll elements. One triggers every 1 second, making sure that an auction hasn't ended, and then updating a clock. The other p:poll is hitting every 60 seconds, doing some calculations and then updating several rows of a table.

Both are working fine.

But when the 60 second one is hitting, and taking several seconds for everything it needs to do, the clock freezes.

These are the two p:poll's:

```
<p:poll listener="#{auctionBean.checkEndGame()}" interval="60" update="placeEditUp lock statusTxt" />
```

and

```
<p:poll listener="#{biddingBean.calcRemainingTime()}" interval="1" update="remHr remMn remSc closingTime prodNameTxt adminMsg" />
```

Any ideas how to prevent the clock from freezing?

Comment: Any insight at all on this? Do the two poll's use the same thread?